# Download server SSL certificate in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, ssl-certificate

Is there anyway I can download the SSL certificate of a server and verify it before trying to connect to it to send data in a blackberry device? I am using `((HttpsConnection)conn).getSecurityInfo();` but it gives a Certificate type which doesnt have much useful info. When i tried to check for the type, it said `net.rim.device.api.crypto.certificate.CertificateUtilities` . Is there any way i can cast this to a X509 Certificate so I have access to bit more useful information ?

Answer (score 3):

Check the class [net.rim.device.api.crypto.certificate.x509.X509Certificate](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/certificate/x509/X509Certificate.html)

UPDATE:
Sorry, my previous answer was wrong: There are two interfaces in the API with the same class name: `net.rim.device.api.crypto.certificate.Certificate` (from which `X509Certificate` extends) and `javax.microedition.pki.Certificate` (the J2ME one). The latter is the one you can retrieve via HttpsConnection, and it is not very useful.

So you are stuck with X509Certificate constructors, and to create an instance you'll need to download the certificate from the server first, or include it in your app resources. In this question you can see how to download a certificate from server:
https://serverfault.com/q/139728/87344. However, this may not be an option for you.

Comment: How do I download the SSL certificate of the server ? Is that possible?

Comment: Is that code working for you? getServerCertificate() returns a type of  javax.microedition.pki.Certificate rather than net.rim.device.api.crypto.certificate.Certificate . so I cant cast cert to X509Certificate

Comment: You are right, these are two different classes. Updated answer, but unless you have access to the certificate it looks complicated.

Comment: Even if I have certificate in app resources, how can I verify that the server certificate is not being faked?

Comment: I'm no security expert, but AFAIK every certificate is issued by a higher authority (CA) in the hierarchy, or a root CA if it is self signed. The BlackBerry device already has a list of trusted root certificates built in, as in most browsers. A certificate is a digitally signed document that can be verified against the signer public key. That is what the `verify` methods are supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to download it beforehand. It is sent during the handshake, and verified, and made available to the application via the SSL Session, after the handshake completes.

Comment: @MichaelDonohue Certainly telling him he doesn't need to do it and that it already happens automically is an answer.

Comment: If you want to provide a quality StackOverflow answer, show some code that takes a BlackBerry HttpsConnection object, after the handshake is complete, and fetches the verified SSL certificate information, preferably in X509 format.

Comment: @MichaelDonohue It's better when you say what you are actually expecting, but to do that I would first need to know what "useful info" is missing from the Certificate object provided by his own code.

Comment: Face facts here. Your answer is inferior for StackOverflow.  @MisterSmith read the whole question, not just the first sentence.  MisterSmith actually understands this is a BlackBerry question, pointed to BlackBerry documentation, and gave an answer to the whole question. You gave an answer which is no better than "Don't worry your pretty little head about the details", ignored the specific request around the BlackBerry API, and then had the gall to ask why you got a downvote.

Comment: @EJP The j2me certificate object doesn't give any information about the certificate chain or finger prints. It doesn't tell about basic constraints either. Plenty of relevant information is not available. This is a limitation of the Rim Apis. Android /IOS provides information about finger prints

Answer (score -2):

Regularly do WINDOWS or MICROSOFT UPDATE and set it for permanent update so as you need not do manualy. SSL certificate will be installed automatically if the update deems it fit. Two months I spent time in vain behind this problem but result was none. Manually correct your time (year, hour, munite) or take help from internet TIME SYNCHRONIZATION from Control Panel - Date and Time - Internet Time - Update Now. Then go to Start - Microsoft update or Windows update. Basically this problems occurs due to Date and Time error. It is very interesting that if you set time even with wrong manner, this certificate error automatically goes away in rare case.