# Download website certificate in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an app where when we visit a secure website i need to download the certificate and access that certificate how can that be available ?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: @PhilipK i mean that when we make a secure connection, i need the ssl certificate file, which is fetch by the device/simulator for the connection

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'net.rim.device.api.crypto.certificate' to get the properties of a certificate.

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/certificate/package-summary.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11933690/773263

Comment: how to get this certificate , means is it available to access from device/simulator after the url is opened? if yes then where and how can we access it